# df.to_excel creates 12MB file. File suddenly shrinks to 4.6 MB when opening and saving again

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a python script in which I write a Pandas dataframe to an excel file. This creates a file of 12MB. However if I open this file in excel and save it again, it suddenly shrinks to 4.6 MB.

I cannot ignore this because I think my script blows up the size somehow. Any idea How I can solve this?

Comment: Actually when I read an excel

alldata = pd.read_excel('alldata.xlsx', index_col=0)

And write the dataframe back to an excel:

alldata.to_excel('C:/Users/jd11179/Documenten/Python/FX statistics/alldata2.xlsx')

The original excel was 4.5 MB and the new one is 11.7 MB. Without doing anything else.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.